# In which case round(a, 2) and f'{a:.2f}' will give a different result? Python

Tags: python, rounding, f-string

I have the following task:

George is going to have guests tonight and he decides to buy bonito, horse mackerel, and mussels. He goes to the fish market to buy a few kilos of each. You enter the prices of mackerel and sprat in USD in the console. You also enter the quantity of bonito, horse mackerel, and mussels in kg. How much money will George need to pay the bill if the prices at the fish market are:

- bonito - 60% more expensive than mackerel
- horse mackerel - 80% more expensive than sprat
- mussels - 7.50 USD/kg

Input:

- First line: price of mackerel (float number)
- Second line: price of sprat (float number)
- Third line: quantity of bonito in kg (float number)
- Fourth line: quantity of horse mackerel in kg (float number)
- Fifth line:  quantity of mussels in kg (integer)

Output:
Result. A float number rounded to the second decimal place.

My code is:

```
sprats_price = float(input())
bonito_kg = float(input())
horse_mackerel_kg = float(input())
mussels_kg = int(input())
 
bonito_price = mackerel_price * 1.6
horse_mackerel_price = sprats_price * 1.8
mussels_price = 7.5
 
bonito_total = bonito_kg * bonito_price
hours_mackerel_total = horse_mackerel_kg * horse_mackerel_price
mussels_total = mussels_kg * mussels_price
 
total = bonito_total + hours_mackerel_total + mussels_total
print(round(total, 2))
```

I got 80/100 points.

When I changed

```
print(round(total, 2))
```

to

```
print(f'{total:.2}')
```

I got 100/100.

So I'm trying to find out in which case there will be a different result?

There are 3 example inputs/outputs:

- Example inputs:
- 6.90
- 4.20
- 1.5
- 2.5
- 1
- Output:
  42.96
- Example inputs:
- 5.55
- 3.57
- 4.3
- 3.6
- 7
- Output:
- 113.82
- Example inputs:
- 7.79
- 5.35
- 9.3
- 0
- 0
- Output:
- 115.92

There is a total of 10 tests.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Is it possible that there is an error in the condition of the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your question asks about `a:.2f`, but you wrote `print(f'{total:.2}')`, so I'm going to use .2f

In the case where the number has trailing zeros,

```
In [1]: x = 5.7899

In [2]: round(x,2)
Out[2]: 5.79

In [3]: f'{x:.2f}'
Out[3]: '5.79'

In [4]: x = 5.7

In [5]: round(x,2)
Out[5]: 5.7

In [6]: f'{x:.2f}'
Out[6]: '5.70'
```